# Animating a ProgressViewStyle inside NavigationView

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, navigationview

Let's make a simple custom "infinite" spinner.

SwiftUI provides `ProgressView` as the prototypical container for this with `ProgressViewStyle` as a means of customizing the way to present the progress.

To make our spinner infinitely spin, we'll use a linear animation, repeat it forever, start it at a rotation effect of 0 and move it to 360 degrees, as soon as the spinner appears.

Simple!

Now let's put it inside a `NavigationView` :

[image: spinner animates up while spinning around]

We see the spinner bouncing up and down as it spins. Any clue what's going on or how to address the issue (while preserving a respect for the fundamentals, eg. `ProgressView` to display progress and `ProgressViewStyle` to customize it)?

```swift
struct SimplePreview: PreviewProvider, View {
    static var previews = Self()
    
    @State
    private var isAnimating = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ProgressView().progressViewStyle(SymbolicStyle())
        }
    }
    
    public struct SymbolicStyle: ProgressViewStyle {
        @State
        private var isAnimating = false

        public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            Image(systemName: "circle.hexagonpath.fill")
                .rotationEffect(self.isAnimating ? .degrees(360) : .zero)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        self.isAnimating = true
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a `.navigationTitle` keeps the spinner's location constant (as long as it's a large title - setting `.navigationTitleBarDisplayMode(.inline)` brings the variation back). Wrapping the progress bar inside a ScrollView also keeps it in a constant position, albeit at the top. I wonder if there's some adjustment to the navigation view's content area that takes place at `.onAppear` time that is also getting animated? Curiously though, an Image on its own (outside the progress view style) works fine…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `.onAppear` with `.task` in order to start the animation in a separate context where it does not get mixed up with other unreleated layout events.